# How do I read and print Binary tree floor by floor?

Tags: algorithm, tree, floor

I have a tree structure in C

```
Node {
   int info;
   Node *left;
   Node *right;
}
```

A binary tree made from nodes. Now I want to print the tree floor by floor. 
ex:

```
1
2  7
1  8  7  0
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What you are looking for is called [`breadth-first search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), but your question is not very clear.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I don't know what to call it

Comment: In your example what do those numbers mean ? Does this mean like the tree given below:

  1 
  /\
 2   7
 /\  /\
1 8  7 0

Comment: Yes, full-tree, each node have two child, except leafs

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use BFS (Breadth-First-Search) Algorithm. Start with root add its children to a Queue. print root itself. Now do the same with the **Top** element in the Queue. Here is a Pseudo-Code for you

```
Queue = {root} //Queue Containing Only root in the first place 
while (Queue is not empty){
    t = Queue.top()
    print(t.info)
    if (t is not a leaf){
        Queue.push(t.left)
        Queue.push(t.right)
    }
}
```

If you want to know more about BFS, you can check the following likns:

https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Breadth-first_search.html

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960215.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRq6p9s8NVg